# Resolve a chain of promises with timeouts. Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, timeout

I have got this.

```
const getPrice = function(database){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        var promises =[];
        for(var i in database){
            promises.push(Update.requestClassifieds(database[i]))
        }
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function(todos){
            return resolve(todos);
        })
})}

Update.prototype.requestClassifieds = function(item){
    var ithis = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       var input = {};
       request({
           url: '',
           method: "GET",
           json: true,  
           body: input
  }, function (error, response, body){
    if (error){
        return resolve(item);
    }
    else if(body){
        return resolve(item);
    }
  }
});
});
}
```

I need to request data for each item in database. So, I created a chain of promises for that.

I am requesting data of an api that has 5 sec of cooldown. So, I need wait 5 sec until resolve next promise in **Promise.all(promises)**.

How Can I setTimeout between each promise in Promise.all ?

Comment: It's a bad idea, one question, why you need to a 5 sec countdown between promises? anything about database access?

Comment: @Kalamarico Api that Im using has 5 sec of cooldown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `Promise` chain in your loop

```
const getPrice = function (database) {
    var promisesChain = Promise.resolve(); // Promise chain
    var todos = []; // results to be stored
    for (var i in database) {
        promisesChain = promisesChain.then(((i) => () => { // create closure to grab database[i]
            return Update.requestClassifieds(database[i])
        })(i)).then((res) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => { // store result of requestClassifieds and resolve after 5sec
                    todos.push(res);
                    resolve();
                }, 500);
            });
        })
    }
    return promisesChain.then(() => {return todos});
};
```

**Running example**

```js
const getPrice = function (database) {
 var promisesChain = Promise.resolve();
 var todos = [];
 for (var i in database) {
  promisesChain = promisesChain.then(((i) => () => {
   return Update.requestClassifieds(database[i])
  })(i)).then((res) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
     todos.push(res);
     resolve();
          console.log('resolve', res);
    }, 1000);
   });
  })
 }
 return promisesChain.then(() => {return todos});
};
const Update = {};
Update.requestClassifieds = function (i) {
 console.log('got', i);
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(i)
 });
}
getPrice({
 a: 'A',
 b : 'B',
 c : 'C'
}).then(console.log);
```

Comment: I think this is best solution. One question: If I want that getPrice return the results as array because I want use them. Just I need to do that in " promisesChain.then(function () {
        console.log(todos); // display results
    })"

Comment: Change `promisesChain.then(function () { console.log(todos); // display results })` to `promisesChain.then(() => {return todos});` so `getPrice` will return `Promise` that resolve with array of results