# Add timer to Promise.all, map

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, promise, request

I would like to add some timeout between below get requests. I mean, flow should be looks like: `timeout, https://example.com/example1, timeout, https://example.com/example2, timeout, https://example.com/example3, timeout` etc. (or without first timeout, whatever).

Below function is working properly:

```
function promiseGetInformationFromMultipleUrls(parts) {
    return Promise.all(parts.map(part => {
      return request({
            'url': `https://example.com/${part}`,
            'json': true
        }).then(partData =>  {console.log("Part data was fetched: " + part); return partData.result;})
          .catch(err => {console.error("Error during fetching data from part: " + part + ", error code: " + err.statusCode);});
    }));
}
```

Where parts is -> example1, example2, example3....

I am trying do it by adding timer:

```
const timer = ms => new Promise( res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

And use it:

```
function promiseGetInformationFromMultipleUrls(parts) {
    return Promise.all(parts.map(part => {
    console.log("wait 1 seconds");
    timer(1000).then(_=>console.log("done"));
      return request({
            'url': `https://example.com/${part}`,
            'json': true
        }).then(partData =>  {console.log("Part data was fetched: " + part); return partData.result;})
          .catch(err => {console.error("Error during fetching data from part: " + part + ", error code: " + err.statusCode);});
    }));
}
```

But it is wrong flow -> `timeout, timeout, timeout,..., get request1, get request 2, get request 3`.

Comment: By “timeout”, you mean “delay”?

Comment: Indeed. Timeout, delay or sleep.

Comment: Promise.all is wrong approach. It will just fire everything at once. You'd use reduce promise array or use await.

Comment: Yes, it is fire everything at once. Hmm, Thank You, I will try to change to promise.reduce.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve a chain of promises with timeouts. Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609804/resolve-a-chain-of-promises-with-timeouts-promise-all)

Comment: @emil To be exact, it's the `map` that fires all calls at once, not `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may reduce it to a Promise chain:

```
function promiseGetInformationFromMultipleUrls(parts) {
 return parts.reduce((chain, part) =>
  chain.then((result) =>
    timer(1000).then(() => 
      request(/*...*/).then(res => 
        result.concat(res)
      )
    )
  ),
  Promise.resolve([])
);
}
```

However thats quite ugly, so you may use async / await instead:

```
 async function promiseGetInformationFromMultipleUrls(parts){
   const result = [];
   for(const part of parts){
     await timer(1000);
     result.push(await request(/*...*/));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The best solution, for me, will be not changing the promise to async process Parts function. The promise from, my question, is only snippet from all script.

Comment: In first proposal - `parts.reduce((chain, part) =>` where is parts? I would like add each of line to url, but there is no parts.

Comment: @profiler i dont get you. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: I am sorry. Regarding to first solution - promise chain. There are nothing about "parts", only part. Where I should slice it and use in request part?

Comment: @profiler `part` is one element of your `parts` array.

Comment: I know, but where is "parts"? There is no "parts" in Your first solution. Och, or I should use that return in promise.all(parts.map....)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162543/discussion-between-profiler-and-jonas-w).

Comment: There is possibility to reuturn the promise (or function) in those solution? Still I have error about expecting a function, no object.

Comment: Ok, I got it! Just use json.stringify. it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
const Fail = function(reason){this.reason=reason;};
const isFail = x=>(x&&x.constructor)===Fail;
const timedoutPromise = time => promise => 
  Promise.race([
    promise,
    new Promise(
      (resolve,reject)=>
        setTimeout(
          x=>reject("timed out"),
          time
        )
    )
  ]);

utls = [];//array of urls
in5Seconds = timedoutPromise(5000);
Promise.all(
  urls.map(
    url=>
      in5Seconds(makeRequest(url))
      .catch(e=>new Fail([e,url]))//failed, add Fail type object
  )
)
.then(
  results=>{
    const successes = results.filter(x=!isFail(x));
    const failed = results.filter(isFail);
    const timedOut = failed.filter(([e])=>e==="timed out");
  }
)
```