# Node.js - async method within a class for loop of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I need to execute a chain of promises with a timer for external requests. As someone suggested in the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094024/7614941) I used async/await and rewrite it a bit:

```
class myClass{
    constructor(symbols){
     this.downloadCsv(symbols)
    }

    // async/await method executing requests with timer
    static async downloadCsv(symbols){
        const result = [];
        symbols.forEach(symbol => {
           await timer(1000)
           result.push(await this.downloadOneCsv(symbol['symbol']) )
        }
        return result
    }

    downloadOneCsv(symbol){
    //request goes here
    }
}
```

While executing a code above I keep receving an error message suggesting that async/await is not valid:

> ```
>      await timer(1000)
>      ^^^^^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are not able to use timer in a `forEach` because of its nature and calling callback functions as much as amount of your array elements in stack. That timer method after adding `async` keyword to the callback function will get fired just once and other times will get skipped. I suggest use `for of` loop on that array.

```
static async downloadCsv(symbols){
    const result = [];
    for (const symbol of symbols) {
       await timer(1000)
       result.push(await this.downloadOneCsv(symbol['symbol']) )
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Old One:

```js
const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7];

arr.forEach(async item => {
  console.log('Before Timer');
  await timer(1000);
  console.log(item);
});
```

### Fixed One

```js
const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7];

(async () => {
  for (const item of arr) {
    await timer(1000);
    console.log(item);
  }
})();
```